# ArrayList in Java Is Showing Weird Memory Result using get

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The expected output of my index 0 Array list is the name and the number. But its showing weird result why?

fullcode here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBUoB.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  Copy the relevant parts of the code and paste them into the question.

Comment: Read [why you should not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Yes, always explain what you are seeing (copy paste again) and explain what you wanted to see instead.  In your case it looks like you didn't override the `toString()` method.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString()

Comment: Thank you everyone the toString is the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't post images. Post the code. If you want to print arrays, then you should use `Arrays.toString` method. Every element in the array should also have a `toString` method. Here is an example:

```
class Student{
    int id;
    String name;
    public Student(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @override
    public String toString(){
        return "Student " + name + ", with id: " + id;
    }
}
```

Then use something like this in the main method:

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.add(new Student(134, "Jake"));
studentList.add(new Student(435, "Mark"));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studentList));
```